# Swift HTML Decoding Trouble

Tags: html, ios, swift

In Swift, I Decoding HTML using `NSAttributedString`, see below:

```
let encodedString = "Phải công nhận rằng kể từ lúc ông Thăng làm bộ trưởng"
let encodedData = encodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)         
let decodedString = attributedString.string
println(decodedString)
```

But the result like this:

> Pháº£i cÃ´ng nháº­n ráº±ng ká»ƒ tá»« lÃºc Ã´ng ThÄƒngÂ lÃ m bá»™
>   trÆ°á»Ÿng

The true result must be the same with the `encodedString`

What's wrong in this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to specify the used character *encoding* in the document options:

```
let encodedString = "Phải công nhận rằng kể từ lúc ông Thăng làm bộ trưởng"
let encodedData = encodedString.data(using: .utf8)!

let attributedOptions : [NSAttributedString.DocumentReadingOptionKey : Any ] = [
    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue ]
do {
    let attributedString = try NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil)
    let decodedString = attributedString.string
    print(decodedString)
} catch {
    // error ...
}

// Output: Phải công nhận rằng kể từ lúc ông Thăng làm bộ trưởng
```

*(Updated for Swift 4)*

Comment: Oh, That's OK. Very thanks @Martin R. But this method is REALLY slow for long content. Any ones optimized for the same purpose?

Comment: @Sonrobby: You could use an XML parser to parse the HTML, but I have no experience with that, so I cannot recommend anything. This might be interesting, although it is written in Objective-C: http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios.

Comment: 'DocumentReadingOptionKey' is unavailable in Swift

Comment: @moonvader: It compiled in my test. Which Xcode/Swift Version are you using?