# change speciel characters in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a string which contain several special characters. Most of them seem to change to the correct characters, however there is 2 which does not seem to want to change. How come that?

Here is a example how the string looks like

```
I’m looking to create a team, but we’re still in the discussion phase 
with the players and the organisations, and nothing is certain.
&rdquo; In addition, Maikel "Maikelele" Bill added the following: &ldquo;
```

code:

```
extension String {
   init(htmlEncodedString: String) {
    let encodedData = htmlEncodedString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let attributedOptions = [NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute: NSHTMLTextDocumentType]
    let attributedString = NSAttributedString(data: encodedData, options: attributedOptions, documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)
    self.init(attributedString!.string)
    }
}
```

viewDidLoad:

```
var testString = "I’m looking to create a team, but we’re still in the discussion phase with the players and the organisations, and nothing is certain. &rdquo; In addition, Maikel \"Maikelele\" Bill added the following: &ldquo;"

println(String(testString))
```

Comment: "&rdquo;" is an "HTML character entity", so this might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25607247/how-do-i-decode-html-entities-in-swift

Comment: did not make any changes?

Comment: Please add some code: A reproducible example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: I've added testCode nu

Comment: You don't call the extension method at all. Try `println(String(htmlEncodedString: testString))`. – That code has a problem with non-ASCII characters, an improved version is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27898167/1187415.